# Reading code from a file

Tags: c, file-io

let me start by saying I have very minimal experience with C.

I'd like to make C read code from an external file, example:

```
switch(status)
{
    case 0:
    {
        read from /path/file1
    break;
    }
    case 1:
    {
        read from /path/file2
    break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        read from /path/file3
    break;
    } 
}
```

(pseudo) Example of what kind of code might be in files 1-3:

```
if((this & that) && !(other & another))
    {code;more code;}
else if(!(this & that) && (other & another))
    {code;more code;}
```

What code should I place where I said "read from /path/file1" to read the code as code and not as a string?

Edit: My aim is to be able to edit "file1, file2, file3" after compilation. I'm editing the source for linux' unofficial "g15" drivers, because "g15macro" (software to edit the macro keys) didn't work out for me, so I've been hardcoding the macros into the drivers. I wanted to make things easier for me so I wouldn't have to re-compile every time I want to edit the macros. (Gnome 15 which is a more recent project than g15daemon doesn't work for me either; I get input delays with it)

Comment: You can't load C-code from other files during run-time. C is a language that is compiled once, and it needs to be complete during the time of compilation. Once the program is compiled and linked to an executable, you can't load and execute arbitrary source code.

Comment: Maybe you can have different executables and have this C code call them based on your case?

Comment: @VusP: Maybe; if I was actually skilled enough in C to write that executable I could, but I'm not too confident.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: actually I think you can do it with libjit. take a look : http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/10/17/getting-started-with-libjit-part-1/

Comment: Why not turn these code files into shared libraries and load them at runtime?

Comment: @filipe-goncalves: That's a good idea I think, I will try that ^_^ (But due to lack of skill my mileage may vary, an example would be great)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to select among executable files and execute depending on selection then you can use `system()` in linux environment.

```
 system("path to executable")
```

If you want to edit and then execute then one way is to edit the source file. Then compile it in your main program and then execute the newly compiled executable code.
It can be done by writing a series commands inside system() in a program.

```
 case 0: edit /path/file1
        system("gcc -o file1 /path/file1")
        system("/path/file1")
```

Comment: Forgot to mark as solution, this solved my problem! I used system("path") to do this, and it worked wonderfully, thanks! I guess using executables is the least amount of pain in this context.

Answer (score 0):

You should study C some more.

As people have already said, C is not interpreted, and so you can't process raw code at runtime.
Each piece of code you need to run must be compiled.

Having said that, you don't need to recompile the whole source if you want to change just some part of your program. That's why people split projects into multiple files, compile them separately and then link the compiled bytecode together (statically or dynamically), while using Makefiles to determine just which parts (which files) of a project need to be recompiled.

Your case statements could contain function calls and those functions could be defined in separate files. On updates, you'd just recompile those files. (If you use dynamic linking, I guess you could have your program call your compiler to recompile a dynamically linked part of itself).